# RxJS concat two observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, concatenation

I am trying to concat two Obs1 and Obs2. Obs1 sends out 5,6,7. Obs2 send out 1,2,3,4. I am concating ->  concat(Obs2, Obs1)

expecting 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in my subscriber, but getting only 1,2,3,4. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let Obs1 = new rxjs.Subject();
let Obs2 = new rxjs.Subject();

function sendToObs1(x){ 
    Obs1.next(x)
}

async function sendToObs2(){
  let trns = await getValues();
  for(let i = 0; i < trns.length; i++){
    Obs2.next(trns[i])
  }
  Obs2.complete()
}

function getValues(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3,4]), 10)
  })
};

rxjs.concat(Obs2, Obs1).subscribe({
  next: x=> console.log("Received: " + x),
  complete: () => console.log("Done")}
)
sendToObs2()

sendToObs1(5)
sendToObs1(6)
sendToObs1(7)

//Output
// Received: 1 
// Received: 2 
// Received: 3 
// Received: 4


//Expected
// Received: 1 
// Received: 2 
// Received: 3 
// Received: 4
// Received: 5
// Received: 6
// Received: 7
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat only subscribes after the onComplete of Obs2

```js
let Obs1 = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();
let Obs2 = new rxjs.Subject();

function sendToObs1(x){ 
    Obs1.next(x)
}

async function sendToObs2(){
  let trns = await getValues();
  for(let i = 0; i < trns.length; i++){
    Obs2.next(trns[i])
  }
  Obs2.complete()
}

function getValues(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([1,2,3,4]), 10)
  })
};

rxjs.concat(Obs2, Obs1).subscribe({
  next: x=> console.log("Received: " + x),
  complete: () => console.log("Done")}
)
sendToObs2()

sendToObs1(5)
sendToObs1(6)
sendToObs1(7)

//Output
// Received: 1 
// Received: 2 
// Received: 3 
// Received: 4


//Expected
// Received: 1 
// Received: 2 
// Received: 3 
// Received: 4
// Received: 5
// Received: 6
// Received: 7
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```